# If the size of the file exceeds the maximum size of the file system, what happens?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, partition

For example, In FAT32 partition, The maximum file size is 4GB. but I was able to create a 5GB file with vim and I saved the file and opened it again, the console output was broken like a staircase. I have three questions.

1. If the size of the file exceeds the maximum size of the file system, what happens?
2. In my case, Why break?
3. In Unix system call, stat() can succeed up to a 2GB(2^31 - 1). Does this have anything to do with the file system? Is there a relationship between the limits of data in stat() and the limits of each feature in the file system?

Comment: `write` will fail with the slightly confusing `ENOSPC` ("No space left on device"); after the third time or so that `cp` failed with that error and I emptyed an USB key to no avail, I learned to check if the size of the file I'm copying exceeds 4 GB before thinking about the space left on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the size of the file exceeds the maximum size of the file system, what happens?

By definition, that can never happens. What really happens is that some system call (probably [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) ...) is failing, and the code doing that should take care of that case.

Notice that [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) filesystems restrict the maximal size of files to 2Gigabytes. Use a better [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) on your USB key if you want more (or [split(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) large files in smaller chunks before copying them to your FAT32-formatted USB key).

If using `<stdio.h>`  notice that [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html), [fclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html) (and most other standard functions) can fail (e.g. because they will do some failing  [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)).

> the console output was broken like a staircase

probably because your [pseudoterminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoterminal) was in some broken state. See [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html), [reset(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reset.1.html), [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

> In Unix system call, stat() can succeed up to a 2GB(2^31 - 1)

You are misunderstanding [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html). Read again its documentation

Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

> I was able to create a 5GB file with `vim`

To understand the behavior of [vim](http://vim.org/) read first its documentation then study its source code (it is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), and you can and perhaps should study its code).

You could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand what system calls are done by some command or process.

Comment: It is file system specific. FAT32 restricts the file size to 2Gb. Format your USB key with a better file system

Comment: On most 64 bits Linux system, the `stat` function from the libc is calling `stat64`

Comment: `stat()` returns the size in a 64 bit variable on 64 bit systems, if you are on a 32 bit system that doesn't use 64 bit types for stat()  -  you can normally compile with the `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to have stat() transparently use the 64 bit variant.